# need suggestion in optimizing below code

Tags: java

I have an array and length is 3 but it may or may not contain data in 3 index , i have to append three queries based on the data in the array. Let me put an example.

```
array[0]="A";
array[1]="B";
array[2]="C";
String strqry1 = "so and so";
String strqry2 = "so and so";
String strqry3 = "so ans so";
String mainQuery = "";
int arrayLength = array.legth;
if(arrayLength == 1 ){
   if(array[0].equals("A")){
     mainQuery = strqry1 ;
   }else if(array[0].equals("B")){
     mainQuery = strqry2 ;
   }else if(array[0].equals("c")){
     mainQuery = strqry3 ;
   }
}
if(arrayLength == 2){
   if(array[0].equals("A") && array[1].equals("B")){
      mainQuery = strqry1 +"union all"+ strqry2 ;
   }else if(array[0].equals("A") && array[1].equals("C")){
      mainQuery = strqry1 +"union all"+ strqry3 ;
   }else if(array[0].equals("B") && array[1].equals("C")){
      mainQuery = strqry2 +"union all"+ strqry3 ;
   }
}
if(arrayLength == 3){
   if(array[0].equals("A") && array[1].equals("B") && array[2].equals("C")){
      mainQuery = strqry1 +"union all"+strqry2 +"union all"+ strqry3 ;
   }
}
```

I need suggestion on , do i need write such permutation and combinations for the 3 sets of If conditions. Any other way i can optimize the code. Please suggest me.

Comment: Your code looks broken. in case of `arrayLength == 1` you then access to `array[1].equals("B")` and `array[2].equals("c")`

Comment: if(arrayLength == 1 ){
this makes no sense, since you created an array with length 3. whether the elements are present or not, an array has a fixed length.
actually: what you are doing in this block:
'if my array can only contain one element, do this and that to the second and third element' ...
you'll need to rework the basics before thinking of optimizing.

Comment: @talex i corrected the question.

Comment: @stultuske i cannot agree with you. because the requirement required such kind of implementation

Comment: @developer in that case, you don't understand how arrays work.
int len = array.length; // in your case this will ALWAYS be 3
if ( len == 1 ){ // this entire if block will never execute
if ( len == 2 ){ // this entire if block will never execute
if ( len == 3 ){ // this one will always execute
this has nothing to do with agreeing with me, this is pure logic.
if ( len == 1 ) --> in the code you posted, this means the array can not have more than one element, yet you are trying to access the second and the third element.

Comment: @Its a dynamic array it may contain one or more elemnts, that i already explained in the question,please check once. I given example with max length . Hope you got it, also yes only one of the if block will be executed in the code that is what iam expecting.

Comment: yes, you explained that, but Java doesn't have dynamic arrays. that is explained in each basic book. if you want dynamic, you'll need a list or a set.
no, it is not what you are expecting. you wrote two entire blocks that will never execute. not even after hell froze over (figure of speach), so, if you expected it that way, why did you write the other blocks in the first place?

Comment: @Stultuske I feel iam not personal on you please, i just asked question and i got the answer what iam expecting . Also its not place to argue. I hope you havenot understood my requirement and code above i given is its dummy code as example and others understood what i need and given the apt answers too. Please leave this here it self. If anything need to corrected from my end i will do it, Thanks for valuable comments.

Comment: All the answers below are very good, but answer from Sorin is more optimiziable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have to use Arrays? It seems more plausible to use a Java Hashmap to do, what you want: Link "A" to strqry1, "B" to strqry2 and "C" to strqry3.

```
import java.lang.StringBuilder;
import java.util.Hashmap;

Map<String, String> myQuery = new Hashmap<String,String>();
myQuery.put("A", strqry1);
myQuery.put("B", strqry2);
myQuery.put("C", strqry3);
```

and then build the needed query:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String queryString;

queryString = myQuery.get(array[0]);
if(queryString != null) {
    sb.append(queryString);
}

// now skip the first entry, proceed the rest
for(int i=1; i<array.length; i++) {
    sb.append(" union all "); // If you want to build a query, watch the whitespaces
    sb.append(queryString);
}
```

This will construct the necessary string without any superfluous "union all" in the string. Your result query will be stored in the StringBuilder sb.

Comment: This won't work when the first value is not "A".The first queryString willd be null, and if you match the second value as "B" or "C" you'll end up having a quiery started by "union all"

Comment: There should be some additional error handling for special cases. Yet to provide that we would need the context (eg: is it suffice to simply "return" if array[0] is null? Can array[0] be null and array[x>0] != null?, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to make method that check one value and return query if value matches. Someting like this.

```
String check(String value) {
    if("A".equals(value)) return strqry1;
    if("B".equals(value)) return strqry2;
    if("C".equals(value)) return strqry3;
    return null;
}
```

And then call this function in loop:

```
String result = "";
for(String value: array) {
    String qry = check(value);
    if(qry==null) continue;
    if(!gry.isEmpty()) gry += "union all";
    result += qry;
}
```

Comment: Dont hope. just check. I belive you have your test casese prepared.

Answer (score 1):

If there's a correlation between the order of the input values, the constants to check, and the resulting query, you could handle these as arrays also:

```
    //constant values to check
    String[] constants={"A", "B", "C"};
    String[] queries={"so and so 1", "so and so 2", "so and so 3"};

    String mainQuery = "";
    String union="";

    for(int i=0; i<array.length && i<constants.length; i++) {

        if(array[i].equals(constants[i])) {
            mainQuery=mainQuery+union+queries[i]+" ";
            union=" union all ";
        }
    }

    System.out.println(mainQuery);
```

New constants and queries could be appended to them, dinamically (as input parameters or object properties...). Also, if you can define them as external configurable values (via injection, properties files, etc), you could change them without rewriting and redeploying your code.